# searching multiple tables in a postgres DB with a single query?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to search multiple tables in a single database but I'm not having any luck.

I have two tables, Cities and Countries and I want a single search that finds results from both/either

Something like this -

```
SELECT * FROM cities && countries WHERE name ='New York'
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: please add an example row of table cities and table countries to clarify what you want exaclty

Answer (score 45):

This can either be done with a `JOIN` or a `UNION` clause. Depending on what you want your result to look like. (I'm making some assumptions about your schema in the following examples):

#### With a JOIN

```sql
SELECT *
FROM cities
JOIN countries ON (cities.country_id = countries.country_id)
WHERE cities.name = 'New York' 
OR countries.name = 'New York'
```

#### With a UNION (use `ALL` if you can, for performance reasons)

```sql
SELECT cities.name, 'Is a city' AS type
FROM cities
WHERE cities.name = 'New York'
UNION ALL
SELECT countries.name, 'Is a country' AS type
FROM countries
WHERE countries.name = 'New York'
```

#### Using `NATURAL FULL JOIN`

[`NATURAL FULL JOIN` may be used to behave similar to a `UNION` if you use it "correctly", as shown in this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/03/07/impress-your-coworkers-with-a-sql-natural-full-outer-join/) or [in this one](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/08/05/use-natural-full-join-to-compare-two-tables-in-sql/).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT 'cities' AS source, cities.* FROM cities) cities
NATURAL FULL JOIN 
  (SELECT 'countries' AS source, countries.* FROM countries) countries
WHERE name = 'New York'
```

Comment: It's important to note that for the UNION solution to work, columns with the same names and types have to be selected from each table (as is the case in Lukas's example).

Comment: @sloreti: Sure, otherwise you can still use that `NATURAL FULL JOIN` trick I've added to my answer...